# Cannot add a reference to c# code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

**My setup - .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008.** I have c# code (inside ssis, but don't worry about ssis). I wanted to be able to use ADODB in my code. So, I added a reference to ADODB. I selected Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library from the COM tab. Then, I added using ADODB as my import.

The sample steps are here -

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ptailor/adodbservice12062005002501am/adodbservice.aspx

But, after running the project, I get an error and I also see that the reference is missing form the list of references. I swear it was there after I added it. How do I fix this problem ?

error-

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.ADODB, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'Interop.ADODB, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at ST_39348fjejencuw92092828303554.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Need for this question -

I was trying to use the code below to get number of rows in an ADO recordset. When I tried to use the code, i kept getting the error "the type or namespace name 'ADODB' could not be found".

```
ADODB.Recordset result = (ADODB.Recordset)Dts.Variables["RESULT_SET"].Value;
int rowCount = result.RecordCount;
MessageBox.Show("rowCount = " + rowCount);
```

Comment: the answer is on microsoft SSIS forums. Same post there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is on microsoft SSIS forums. Same post there. Once you add a reference, just do save all using ctrl+shift+s or simply do it from File > Save all. If you don't do this, then references dont get saved. Silly. Ctrl+s only saves code and nothing else. I wonder why.

---

**Some things I tried before i found the answer**

Based on the comments my question got - If you want to change "target platform" to x86 for Visual Studio 2008 for SSIS, ie BIDS, then Go to build -> configuration manager -> you can see some platform options there. Try fiddling with them if you want.

But, there are consequences of changing your platform as mentioned here -
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ff154ba9-0793-4c19-8896-4fbdc119a6a3/could-not-load-file-or-assembly?forum=sqlintegrationservices#6916a8e9-8ae5-46c3-8cd2-9150dbc14bc6

> Is there a possibility of facing any problems if i execute package in
>   32 bit mode ? is there any disadvantage to it ?

--

> The only major disadvantage is your package cannot use more than 2GB
>   of memory for processing. If your package has low-memory needs, then
>   executing in 32bit mode is absolutely fine.

Answer (score -1):

while running the project from visual studio force the platform target as 32 bit using following steps:

```
->Right click on Project
->Select Properties
->Goto Build Options
->Change  "Platform Target" from "ANY CPU" to "X86"
```

now run the Project.

Comment: I can try this, but I want to know if this setting could cause any problems in the future. I don't know, maybe if i do this, my code wont run on X64 system ? right/wrong ???

Comment: @blasto :it works on both 32 bit and 64 bit systems.

Comment: thanks. I will try this. Can you tell me why the error occurs ?

Comment: There is no "Platform Target" in Build tab. Now what ?

Comment: if you are using vs 2008 then : Go Build->Configuration Manager...
Change 'Active Solution Platform' to x86

Comment: go to Tools -> Options.
In the tree-view on the left hand side, select "Projects and Solutions".
In the options on the right, check the box that says, "Show advanced build configuraions."

Comment: Thanks. But now, there is another problem. Only "Active(Any CPU)" is present in dropdown menu. The post which helps with that is -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136884/visual-studio-2008-project-properties-build-configuration-missing-options I am trying it now.

Comment: Great, the above link does not help me.

Comment: i think you are looking at "Platform" look at "Platform Target"

Comment: Yes, my bad. I was looking at only Platform. But there is no Platform Target. This is so weird.

Comment: okay, i just added a photo. The advanced button in the photo has no platform target.

Comment: But, I think i found how to change the platform. Adding it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

As the Exception suggests the FileNotFoundException occurs when :

> The exception that is thrown when an attempt to access a file that does not exist on disk fails.

Also Interop.ADODB is created when you reference a COM object. Go to bin\debug folder of your project and see if you can find the Interop.ADDODB file.
    If you cannot find it than you should check the integrity of the *.dll file that you are referencing.

Comment: I went to my SSIS project folder. There is a bin folder, but no debug folder. Now, I am confused.

Comment: Did you build the project?

Comment: ok, so i followed the steps from the link and i successfully created the project (built it and with no error/warnings whatsoever). From what i see in the link is that you should reference Microsoft ActiveX Data object **2.7** not 2.8 as you said you referenced. Try to reference Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.7.

Comment: The strangest thing happened. I added 2.7. Then, I just ran my code and got what i wanted. When I came back to the code, I still get the error - the type or namespace name 'ADODB' could not be found. I have to add the reference again for the code to run. Really weird. Bug perhaps ???