# Can't set platform to x86 in Visual Studio 2008 C# Express Edition

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I want to set the target platform of my project to x86, but there is no such option in the "Platform" dropdown list.

[image: Configuration manager]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on `<New ...>` to define a new x86 only configuration.

[image: define cpu architectrue]

Answer (score 1):

This is a *very* common mistake and very hard to eradicate.  Haven't quite given up hope yet.

The Platform name of a project only matters to C++ projects.  Where it is a big deal,  *different* compilers are used to generate the program since unmanaged code is machine code that is directly executed by the processor.  So it is very important that you properly select between x86, x64 and ARM when you build the program.  The Platform selection determines what compiler is used.

It is a non-issue for managed code.  Compilers don't generate machine code, they generate MSIL.  The Just In Time compiler at **runtime** generates the machine code.  And will do so based on the kind of operating system you execute your code on.  A Windows RT slate or a phone will use the ARM jitter.  If you run it on the 64-bit version of Windows on a desktop machine or server then the x64 jitter gets the job done.  And the x86 jitter takes care of a 32-bit operating system.  Nobody cares about Itanium anymore.

So it doesn't matter what the platform name is when you *build* the program, the assemblies generated by the compiler are identical whatever name you pick.  If you want to pick a name for the Platform, VS requires one, then "AnyCPU" is a very appropriate name.  Don't change it.

You *do* have the option to force the CLR to use a different jitter than the default one.  Which works in exactly *one* case, you can force the x86 jitter to be used on a 64-bit operating system.  Purely because the 64-bit version of Windows does support executing x86 programs.  There only one scenario where that is necessary, you may have a dependency on a DLL that contains unmanaged code that's only available as a 32-bit executable.

That forcing is done with a **completely** different setting, changing the Platform name does **nothing**.  You find it back in Project + Properties, Compile tab for a C# project.  Only the setting for the EXE project matters.

Answer (score 0):

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136884/visual-studio-2008-project-properties-build-configuration-missing-options)

Go Build->Configuration Manager...

Change 'Active Solution Platform' to x86 (if it's there. If only AnyCPU is there, then use that.)

For each offending project, in the Platform column, select 'New'

Choose New Platform as 'x86', Copy Settings from 'Any CPU', and make sure the check box is NOT ticked.

[image]